# Remote deployment hangs with Netbean/Glassfish

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish, remote-server

I have two fairly simple maven project on my netbeans. Both are configured to run on a remote glassfish server.

I can easily deploy the first one using the "run" button, however, if I try to "run" the second, the deploying action hangs indefinitely and doesn't do anything. No error, even on the remote glassfish logs.

Both have the same dependancies and the same configuration on Netbean. The second just have more web page and Java classes.

Any idea what would be causing this ? I can't make any sense of that.

Thanks !

Edit : If I delete all the Java classes, the deployment is working, this doesn't make any sense.

Edit² : If I manually deploy both application using the Glassfish web interface, it's working fine.

Comment: Go to View > IDE Log, and show the error message.

Comment: They have different context paths? Somewhat like `localhost:8080/app1/` and `localhost:8080/app2/`

Comment: There are no error message on the IDE log. Both have different context paths.